# ios7; custom back button; setBackIndicatorImage + setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage

Tags: ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, back-button

I'm trying to set my image instead of standard back arrow in navigation bar. It looks like

```
UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(12, 22);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0f);
[tmpImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
UIImage *backButtonImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[UIBarButtonItem.appearance setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -64) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:backButtonImage];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:backButtonImage];
```

The problem is sometimes it works, sometimes doesn't. Moreover it depends on build but not on launch. I mean that in one build it might works, after rebuilding (even there is not any changes) it might doesn't work. If my back button works in some build, it works w/o respect of how many times I launch app.

Does anybody have ideas how to fix it?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
I tried w/o using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
The result is the same...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it from the AppDelegate.m but I couldn't.
In the end I made static method that generates button like this:

```
+(UIBarButtonItem*) backButton: (id)target selector:(SEL)selector{

    UIViewController* controller=(UIViewController*)target;
    [controller.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

    UIImage* backImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backbtniphonetrimed.png"];
    UIButton* backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [backBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, backImg.size.width , backImg.size.height)];
    [backBtn setImage:backImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backBtn addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if ([UIImage imageNamed:@"backbtniphonetrimed.png"] != nil){
        [backBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbtniphonetrimed.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }

    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backBtn];
}
```

Then in the controller in viewDidLoad method I just called it and implemented back method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[UIHelper backButton:self selector:@selector(back)];
}

-(void) back{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```